# Delphi: Minimize application to systray

Tags: windows, delphi, taskbar, systray

I want to minimize a Delphi application to the systray instead of the task bar.

The necessary steps seem to be the following:

1. Create icon which should then be displayed in the systray.
2. When the user clicks the [-] to minimize the application, do the following:

   1. Hide the form.
   2. Add the icon (step #1) to the systray.
   3. Hide/delete the application's entry in the task bar.
3. When the user double-clicks the application's icon in the systray, do the following:

   1. Show the form.
   2. Un-minimize the application again and bring it to the front.
   3. If "WindowState" is "WS_Minimized" set to "WS_Normal".
   4. Hide/delete the application's icon in the systray.
4. When the user terminates the application, do the following:

   1. Hide/delete the application's icon in the systray.

That's it. Right?

How could one implement this in Delphi?

I've found the following code but I don't know why it works. It doesn't follow my steps described above ...

```
unit uMinimizeToTray;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ShellApi;

const WM_NOTIFYICON = WM_USER+333; 

type
  TMinimizeToTray = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure CMClickIcon(var msg: TMessage); message WM_NOTIFYICON;
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  MinimizeToTray: TMinimizeToTray;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMinimizeToTray.CMClickIcon(var msg: TMessage);
begin
  if msg.lparam = WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK then Show;
end;

procedure TMinimizeToTray.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
VAR tnid: TNotifyIconData;
    HMainIcon: HICON;
begin
  HMainIcon := LoadIcon(MainInstance, 'MAINICON');
  Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, @tnid);
  tnid.cbSize := sizeof(TNotifyIconData);
  tnid.Wnd := handle;
  tnid.uID := 123;
  tnid.uFlags := NIF_MESSAGE or NIF_ICON or NIF_TIP;
  tnid.uCallbackMessage := WM_NOTIFYICON;
  tnid.hIcon := HMainIcon;
  tnid.szTip := 'Tooltip';
  Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, @tnid);
end;

procedure TMinimizeToTray.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caNone;
  Hide;
end;

end.
```

Comment: It used to be that the TApplication was the one that created the taskbar entry, and the TForms were free to act independently. Has this changed as of late?

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using? In newer versions, there is a TTrayIcon in the VCL, that you can use to create the tray icon, at least.

Comment: The code is different with your steps in that; - the systray icon is always visible, - it does not interfere with 'minimizing' (there's no step 2), when the icon is double clicked it shows the form which was hidden by clicking the close box [X], - and also it does not take terminating into account (there's no step 4).

Comment: The TTrayIcon with implementing the DoubleClick and ApplicationMinimize events is the easiest using VCL components.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand: Unfortunately, I use Delphi 7. It doesn't seem to be implemented there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using CoolTrayIcon. The author has already worked out all the issues involved with tray icons.  Its free with source and examples and very debugged.

http://subsimple.com/delphi.asp

Comment: This component works fine. It does everything one wants to have for a TrayIcon. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If it still works, it's probably easiest to use [JVCL](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/)'s [TJvTrayIcon](http://help.delphi-jedi.org/item.php?Id=170513) to handle it automatically.

Comment: Probably, I'm just to stupid, but I didn't found a download link for this. Thanks, though! ;) If you look at the +3 votes, your answer seems to be good ...

Comment: It's the "Downloads" link on the left at the first link.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of  `Application.BringToFront;` use `SetforegroundWindow(Application.Handle);`

Answer (score -1):

**In the following text I'll be referring to the step numbers mentioned in the question:**

The following solution is without any additional components. It's very easy to implement.

**Step #1:**

Just use the application's main icon (see following code).

**Step #2:**

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Minimize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, @TrayIconData);
  Form1.Hide;
end;
```

**Step #3:**

```
procedure TForm1.TrayMessage(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if Msg.lParam = WM_LBUTTONDOWN then begin
    Form1.Show;
    Form1.WindowState := wsNormal;
    Application.BringToFront;
    Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, @TrayIconData);
  end;
end;
```

**Step #4:**

```
procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, @TrayIconData);
end;
```

**Necessary code in interface part:**

```
uses
  [...], ShellApi;

const
  WM_ICONTRAY = WM_USER + 1;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    [...]
    procedure TrayMessage(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_ICONTRAY;
  end;
```

**The only problem: The application can be minimized to the systray only once. The next time you want to minimize it, nothing will happen. Why?**

Source: [delphi.about.com](http://delphi.about.com/od/kbwinshell/l/aa121801a.htm)