# Hiding application from taskbar in Delphi doesn't work

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I want my application to minimize to the system tray, and not be visible on the taskbar. I followed the suggestions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11821810/4759426) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23990189/4759426) answer and changed the `MainFormOnTaskBar` property in the project source:

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.MainFormOnTaskBar := False;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Next I tried this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.Hide;
  WindowState := wsMinimized;
  TrayIcon1.Visible := True;
end;
```

and this variant:

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Minimize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.Hide;
  WindowState := wsMinimized;
  TrayIcon1.Visible := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.Minimize;
end;
```

but while the tray icon shows correctly the application still shows in the taskbar. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's the application window that you see on the task bar. Hide it.

Comment: Presumably ShowWindow will do the job for you. I don't think that TApplication exposes anything beyond the window handle.

Answer (score 2):

David suggests that what I see in the taskbar is not my main form, but my application. Following his advice I hid that using `ShowWindow`:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.Hide;
  WindowState := wsMinimized;
  TrayIcon1.Visible := True;

  ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_Hide);
end;
```

Problem solved. Thanks, David.

Comment: When `Application.MainFormOnTaskBar` is True, the `Application.MainForm` window controls the taskbar button (amongst other things). When False instead, the `Application` window controls the taskbar button. You should strive to leave `MainFormOnTaskbar` to True, it is really needed for proper OS interactions on Vista+, setting it to False has MANY subtle consequences throughout the VCL, as MANY things have a (misguided) dependency on `MainFormOnTaskbar` being True. You should not have to set it to False just to accomplish what you are asking for.